# Botulism in oil packed foods

Tags: food-safety, botulism

We hear all about botulism in garlic oil and the needed preventive measures. Is this only true of garlic or is it just more common. For example I make a oil packed fish (oil, salt onions, jalapeño, fish) I’ve been making this for years with no problems. Have I just been lucky or is my keeping it in the fridge what’s saved me and if so how long is safe?

Answer (score 2):

Any low-oxygen low-acid environment with sufficient moisture can lead to the growth of botulism (see page 6 of [this USDA guide to canning](https://nchfp.uga.edu/publications/usda/GUIDE01_HomeCan_rev0715.pdf)). Botulism spores are present throughout your kitchen, not just on garlic. To can low-acid foods safely, you need to use a pressure canner for a sufficiently long processing time.

Refrigeration slows down the growth of botulism. The CDC [recommends](https://www.cdc.gov/botulism/prevention.html) storing garlic or herb infused oils in the fridge for at most 4 days. You should be at least this cautious with your oil-packed fish.

Comment: So if you use a pressure canner, no problems with garlic oil, or pesto, or herb oil?